# What are the checkmark (✅) and cross/X (❌) icons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons

I'm trying to display tick (✅) and cross (❌) icons using Flutter. I have this code:

```
child: SlideAction(
    sliderButtonIconPadding: 8,
    text: Slidewords,
    textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: (18),
        color: Colors.white),
    key: key,
    submittedIcon: formvalid
          ? const Icon(Icons.visibility) // tick icon
          : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off), // cross icon
    onSubmit: () async {
        Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 1),
          () => key.currentState!.reset(),
        );
        _trySubmitForm();
    })
```

Clearly the `Icons.visibility` and `Icons.visibility_off` values don't work, but I can't find the right ones [in the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't seem to work to search on that page and it isn't very responsive.

I also tried `Icon.tick`, `Icon.correct`, and `Icon.cross`; none of these give me the result I want.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For a cross, use `Icons.close`, and for a tick, `Icons.check`.

Answer (score 12):

The icons you're looking for are [`Icons.check_box`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/check_box-constant.html) and [`Icons.close`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/close-constant.html). For check icon without the filled box around it, use [`Icons.check`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/check-constant.html).

[image: Icons screenshot]

---

If it's hard to search for icons in the Flutter docs, you can use the [Material Symbols and Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) page from Google Fonts.

After finding the icon, you can click on it and a sidebar will appear on the right side. Go to the "Android" tab, the icon code will be the same as the one from the `Icons` class. For example, here's what you'll get if you click on the "Check Box" icon:

[image: Material Symbols icon example]

The code for this icon is "check_box", so you can use it in Flutter like this:

```dart
Icon(Icons.check_box)
```

In case there are icons you find in that page but not available in the [Icons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) class, you can use the [material_symbols_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons) package. Now instead of using `Icons`, you can use [`Symbols`](https://pub.dev/documentation/material_symbols_icons/latest/symbols/Symbols-class.html):

```dart
// Import the package
import 'package:material_symbols_icons/symbols.dart';

// In your widget, use it as the IconData the same way as Icons
Icon(Symbols.add_task)
```